# The 360-degree video moves slightly to the side

Tags: google-vr, 360-virtual-reality, vrvideoview

I made a 360 degree video player using VrVideoView. I put the player on my smartphone and played video. Then, I confirmed that the front (center) of the video moved slightly to the side. It seems to turn about 15 degrees in about one minute.

http://trimensions.org/node/83

I took the sample code from here and made some modifications.
I do not know  whether reason the video moves finely is the limit of the current hardware or I have made a mistake in my code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have straightened up some of your sentences, and hope I have made your meaning more clear. It is very likely, however, that no one will attempt to answer your question since you did not provide the actual code that you using, so someone could tell if you had made a mistake.

Comment: https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/releases/tag/vv1.180.0
Among the code provided by Google at the address above, I found the same problem in samples-sdk-simplevideowidget. Even if the smartphone don't  any movement, the yaw value changes little by little.
So I searched the internet hard. As a result, I read that the gyro sensor accumulates the error value and the error becomes larger. So, I wonder if the problem I'm having is due to the error of the gyro sensor. If so, I wonder what I can do programmatically.